# Swift UIViewPropertyAnimator automatically plays when leaving app

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10, uiviewpropertyanimator

Good day everyone!

I've a problem with my app. I'm using an UIViewPropertyAnimator to animate my blur. I let the blur effect run from nil (0) to .light (1) but because the light effect is just too much I set the UIViewPropertyAnimator to 0.1 (.fractioncomplete = 0.1).

This works greath! But the problem is that if you leave the app (not kill, just leaving by pressing home button or going to another app), it automatically plays and goes from 0.1 to 1.

I think this is a bug? I hope someone has a solution for this.

Here some pictures: (not enough reputation to post them directly)

[picture with blur on 0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt0wL.jpg)

[picture with blur on 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rH1t.jpg)

Code:

```
let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: nil)
var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?
```

viewdidload:

```
effectView.frame = view.bounds
effectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
mainView.addSubview(effectView)
animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear) {
   self.effectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
}
```

blur action (need to start/pause first because of a known bug from apple to wake the animator up):

```
self.animator?.startAnimation()
self.animator?.pauseAnimation()
self.animator?.fractionComplete = CGFloat(0.1)
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you post the code where you set blur to 0, 1 and 0.2 and method that encloses it? what do you have in your `viewWillAppear` `viewDidAppear` methods of relevant view controller?

Comment: @WladekSurala Thanks for your reply, I've updated my answer.

Comment: so in what method exactly do you set this fractionComplete on your animator?

Comment: @WladekSurala so first, the screen is normal, then you, let's say, press a button and a view pops up. The background with some buttons are under the blurview and when the button is pressed, action blur() get's called where you can find the fractioncomplete (last code block in my question)

Comment: Good that you provided this info, congrats on first good question in SO, check my answer:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your issue, and confirm this behavior, but I doubt it's a bug. Property animator just returns from paused state to active and runs animation. To overcome it you have to `stop` it and then `finish` in **current** fraction of the state (respective states are described in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewanimating)). One more issue here - somehow stopping it right after setting `fractionComplete` stops it at 0 so you have to wait a while (very short). Try this code under your "blurAction":

```
    self.animator?.startAnimation()
    self.animator?.pauseAnimation()
    self.animator?.fractionComplete = CGFloat(0.1)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { 
        self.animator?.pauseAnimation()
        self.animator?.stopAnimation(true)
        self.animator?.finishAnimation(at: .current)
    }
```

I verified it works for background/foreground app lifecycle change.

Comment: Thanks for your time ! It works. But there's a new problem... How can I make the animator active again? I tried with the 3 lines: start, pause and fractionComplete but the app crashes with this error: 
An animator must have at least one animation block to start!'

Comment: ah, you want to get back you animation "alive"? Take a look in documentation. Crash you get is from the fact that you already finished this animator, and need to restart it with animation block (the code you use to set blur on effect view)

Comment: It's fixed now and works perfectly. Thanks! I've made a method to check if the app comes back active and I moved the viewdidload code where I set the blur on effectview to that new method.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this issue by setting the `pausesOnCompletion` property of `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to `true`, immediately after setting the `fractionComplete`. No need to restart the animator.

Comment: For me accepted answer didn't work and this one did. Nice and simple 

Comment: Thanks! You've just saved my day. Your answer should be the accepted one!